# why do I get 'no implicit conversion of String into Integer' in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep getting 'no implicit conversion of String into Integer' when trying to run my model and the following;

```
def self.pull

fbstory = User.current.facebook.get_connection("me", "home")

fbstory.each do |story|
  unless exists?(fb_id: story["id"])
        User.current.new_fbtimeline_stories.create({fb_shares: story.first["shares"]["count"], fb_creation: story["created_time"], fb_message: story["message"], fb_status_type: 'new' })
    end
 end

end
```

and if I do this in the console it works fine but I need to do `.each do |story|`

```
fbstory = User.current.facebook.get_connection("me", "home").first
fbstory["shares"]["count"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`story` is an array, and needs to be indexed numerically. You have `story["created_time"]`. You can't index arrays with strings. You need to use `story.first['created_time']` as you have elsewhere on that line.

Comment: But since there's more then one array returned, how do I split them up without .each and do create entry into DB